# LaTeX {scrreprt} page numbering

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I'm writing in LaTeX a `scrreprt` onesided document, for which I would like to number the pages on the right side of the footer (don't need anything more in the footer). I've found this:

http://notfaq.wordpress.com/2006/10/04/latex-customize-page-numbering/

this is exactly what I need, but the right enumeration is only within chapters from the second side, on the first page of every chapter it doesn't work and default is used (number in the middle of the footer)

Do you have some ideas how to fix it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Werner is right, that question contains yours.  The problem is that the `\chapter` macro resets page style, so you need to reissue it.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
\chapter{title}\thispagestyle{fancy}
```

Comment: this is very helpful, but do u know how to delete this line above?

Comment: What line? Please, show us a minimal code.

Comment: @user2339479: In [the link you provide](http://notfaq.wordpress.com/2006/10/04/latex-customize-page-numbering/) it mentions `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` which is meant to remove the rule in the header. Since `\chapter` page styles are `plain` by default, setting it to `fancy` this way (with *all* the details included in your link) should leave you without a line in the header/above.

Comment: @user2339479, based on the comments above, I understood now. I was supposing that you were using all the commands from that link.

Comment: sorry, indeed this question has already been asked; my mistake after the suggestion to use \chapter{title}\thispagestyle{fancy} was that I didn't use the code I'd found earlier, now everything works, thanks! :)